# What am I doing wrong in this C++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool newgame;

    std::cout << " Ready to waste more family money gambling? y/n ";
    std::cin >> newgame;
    if (newgame = "n")
    {       
        newgame = false;
        return(123);
    }
    else if (newgame = "y")
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int number = rand() % 10;
        int guess;
        std::cout << "Pick your number ";
        std::cin >> guess;
        if (guess == number)
        {
           std::cout << "Winner!";
        }

        else
        {
           std::cout << "Loser!";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I've done wrong here, all that happens is the command prompt closes after I type either "y" or "n".
I've tried everything, from changing the loop types, to even rearranging the code, but everything I try is fruitless.

Comment: You're comparing newgame incorrectly.  For one thing, you're using the assignment operator ('=') rather than the equality operator ('==').  For another thing, you're comparing a boolean to a string, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Always compile with warnings enabled, and when you get warnings, *pay attention to them*.

Comment: Another case of bug of the century...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that == is the operator for equality, not = which is for assignment. What is happening is that this part here,

```
if (newgame = "n")

{       newgame = false;
        return(123);
}
```

Is executing and exiting with 123. Booleans do not store "yes" and "no" values, they store 1 for true, and 0 for false.

Comment: There is implicit conversion from a pointer to `bool`; the result is `false` if the pointer is a null pointer, and `true` otherwise.   `"n"` is not a `std::string`, it's an array of `char const` which decays to a pointer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that conversion existed. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

a `bool` can only hold the values 0 or 1 (true or false). Try changing `newgame` to a `char`. Also, you're using assignment (`=`) instead of equality (`==`).

Also, if you're trying to loop (as I think you implied in your question) you'll want to wrap everything outside your variable declarations in a `do...while` loop.

Comment: Thanks pal, I wish I could accept two answers, because your answer helped me very well too. The do...while loop was the answer to the problems, and all I need to do now is format the visible words so they aren't all on one line. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking too close but I see lots of if blah = something, I think you probability want to use == rather than =  ,  = inside an if statement does an assignment == does a comparision